# ASM Dynamic Sub Class Creation - NoClassDefFoundError BeanInfo

Tags: java, class, dynamic, java-bytecode-asm, beaninfo

I am trying to create a sub class dynamically using ASM Framework.
I am able to create the class and instantiate it. But when I try to do

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(processedEntity, entity);
```

It throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/wheelsup/app/benefits/service/XpOWErhNBiBeanInfo (wrong name: com/wheelsup/app/benefits/service/XpOWErhNBi)
```

Here's the code that I am using to create the subclass:

```
Class<? extends T> get() throws Exception {
    String superClassInternalName = getInternalName(superClass);

    String subClassSimpleName = RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, false);
    String subClassInternalName = getClass().getPackage().getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/").concat("/").concat(subClassSimpleName);
    String subClassName = getClass().getPackage().getName().concat(".").concat(subClassSimpleName);

    ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    classWriter.visit(Opcodes.V1_6,
            ACC_PUBLIC,
            subClassInternalName,
            null,
            superClassInternalName,
            null);

    visitDefaultConstructor(classWriter, superClassInternalName);

    classWriter.visitEnd();

    return SubClassLoader.<T>init().load(classWriter.toByteArray(), subClassName);
}

private void visitDefaultConstructor(ClassWriter classWriter, String superClassInternalName) {
    MethodVisitor methodVisitor = classWriter.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
    methodVisitor.visitCode();
    methodVisitor.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
    methodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, superClassInternalName, "<init>", "()V");
    methodVisitor.visitInsn(RETURN);
    methodVisitor.visitMaxs(0, 0);
    methodVisitor.visitEnd();
}

private static class SubClassLoader<T> {
    private final ClassLoader contextClassLoader;

    private SubClassLoader(ClassLoader contextClassLoader) {
        this.contextClassLoader = contextClassLoader;
    }

    static <U> SubClassLoader<U> init() {
        return new SubClassLoader<>(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<? extends T> load(byte[] classBytes, String className) throws Exception {
        return (Class<? extends T>) new SubClassLoader.DynamicClassLoader(contextClassLoader, classBytes).loadClass(className);
    }

    private static class DynamicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        private byte[] rawClassBytes;

        private DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader contextClassLoader, byte[] classBytes) {
            super(contextClassLoader);
            this.rawClassBytes = classBytes;
        }

        @Override
        public Class findClass(String name) {
            return defineClass(name, this.rawClassBytes, 0, this.rawClassBytes.length);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the *BeanInfo* thing; what is it? and How can I solve my issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `findClass` implementation tries to return the one generated class, regardless of which class the caller asks for. In some situations, failing to load a class, is the right thing to make an operation work.

The `BeanUtils` class relies on the [`Introspector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/beans/Introspector.html) which allows an optional explicit beaninfo implementation for the inspected class, so if being asked for the `BeanInfo` of `Foo`, it will try to load a class `FooBeanInfo` first and if this fails, it will construct a generic bean info for `Foo`.

But since your `findClass` implementation tries to (re)construct the `XpOWErhNBi` class under the wrong name `XpOWErhNBiBeanInfo` instead of reporting the absence of `XpOWErhNBiBeanInfo`, things go wrong.

You have to change your `SubClassLoader` to receive the expected name of the generated class. Then, you can change the `findClass` implementation to

```
@Override
public Class findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if(!name.equals(expectedName))
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
    return defineClass(name, this.rawClassBytes, 0, this.rawClassBytes.length);
}
```

A simpler, but hacky, solution would be to `null` out the `rawClassBytes` after the first class construction and throw a `ClassNotFoundException` for each subsequent class loading request as the inherited standard `loadClass` implementation guarantees to invoke `findClass` for not already loaded classes only, so as long as your program logic of immediately loading the generated class does not change, all subsequent requests are about different, unsupported classes.

However, since the critical point is that the program logic must not change, I don’t recommend that hacky, fragile solution. Passing the name of the generated class to your custom loader and verify it, is a bit more code at first, but much cleaner.

Comment: thanks Holger! I found the solution after I took a look into the ClassLoader impl that is used in the ByteBuddy Framework which was exactly what you said.

Answer (score 1):

so the issue was in the ClassLoader

```
private static class SubClassLoader<T> {
    private final ClassLoader contextClassLoader;

    private SubClassLoader(ClassLoader contextClassLoader) {
        this.contextClassLoader = contextClassLoader;
    }

    static <U> SubClassLoader<U> init() {
        return new SubClassLoader<>(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<? extends T> load(byte[] classBytes, String className) throws Exception {
        return (Class<? extends T>) new DynamicClassLoader(contextClassLoader, classBytes, className).loadClass(className);
    }

    private static class DynamicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        private byte[] classBytes;
        private final String className;

        private DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader contextClassLoader, byte[] classBytes, String className) {
            super(contextClassLoader);
            this.classBytes = classBytes;
            this.className = className;
        }

        @Override
        public Class findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            if (StringUtils.equals(this.className, className)) {
                return defineClass(className, this.classBytes, 0, this.classBytes.length);
            }

            throw new ClassNotFoundException(className);
        }
    }
}
```